# How to save longitude latitude gps in sqlite android?

Tags: android, sqlite, gps

How to save coordinate gps latitude and longitude of the location changed in the database sqlite each given one hour.

Here is my code,

```
public void onLocationChanged(  final Location location) { 
        Log.e("GPS", "Latitude " + location.getLatitude() + " et longitude " + location.getLongitude());
         BDHandler = new DatabaseHandler(null);
         db = BDHandler.getWritableDatabase();
     Thread th= new Thread() {
         public void run()
         {

         ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
            value.put("LONGITUDE", Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
            value.put("LATITUDE", Double.toString( location.getLongitude()));
            { try
            {
         while(true)
         {
             Thread.sleep(360000);
             {
                 db.insert("Table_name", null, value);
             }
         }

            }
            catch(Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            }
         }

         };
            th.start();


        }
```

Comment: while true insert will insert always the same data, as you, like, don't change it.

Comment: so whats the problem with it?

Answer (score 1):

You are storing lat/long as string which uses at least tripple the space needed. store them as float or better as int, by multiplyimg with 1e7.